# Export Joomla template and extensions

Tags: joomla

This is my first time building a Joomla template so I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it right.

I setup my joomla installation on my machine and added extensions to it - plus the customizations needed for the extensions and the template.

Once I install the template to a website, how do I include all the extensions with it (and the configuration of the extensions)? Or do I have to setup it all up all over again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set it up again.  Extensions aren't part of the template.  The Template defines the layout of the site, and the locations on the page where extensions can be added, but it doesn't include the extensions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way. Rather than messing around with installing everything again, simply install Akeeba Backup. You really should have that installed anyhow. In any case, you can make a backup of the entire site including the database, then upload it to your host and run the built in install. It takes longer to upload the file than it does to make the backup and install it. When you are done you will have an exact copy of the site including extensions, templates, and configuration.